# Changing case of letters in unicode string containing accent and local letters

Tags: python, string, unicode, case-sensitive

Python string and unicode objects have following methods for string case conversion.

- `upper()`
- `lower()`
- `title()`

Using unicode strings, I can handle nearly all characters in my local alphabet:

```python
test_str = u"ças şak ürt örkl"
print test_str.upper()
>> ÇAS ŞAK ÜRT ÖRKL
```

Except two letters. Since I am living in Turkey, I have typical [`Turkish I problem`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/).

In my local alphabet, we have a letter `İ` which is similar to `I` and their case conversion must be like following

### `I → lowercase → ı`

### `i → uppercase → İ`

And yes, it spoils ASCII conversion of `i --> I` since `i` and `I` are two separate letters.

```python
test_str = u"ik"
print test_str.upper()
>> IK  # Wrong! must be İK
test_str = u"IK"
print test_str.lower()
>> ik  # Wrong! must be ık
```

How can I overcome this? Is there a way to handle case conversions correctly with using python build-ins?

Comment: You might consider reading [i and I in Turkish](http://blog.yjl.im/2011/08/i-and-i-in-turkish.html).

Answer (score 5):

Python currently doesn't have any support for locale-specific case folding, or the other rules in Unicode SpecialCasing.txt. If you need it today, you can get them from [PyICU](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU).

```
>>> unicode( icu.UnicodeString(u'IK').toLower(icu.Locale('TR')) )
u'ık'
```

Although if all you care about is the Turkish I, you might prefer to just special-case it.